# Returning nested objects from Blazor API to WASM

Tags: c#, api, blazor

I'm learning Blazor, and creating a website with a simple image viewer.

I have the following classes describing an Image and any Tags that are related:

```
public class GalleryImage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GalleryImageTag> ImageTags { get; set; }
}

public class GalleryImageTag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GalleryImage> GalleryImages { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see they describe a many-to-many relationship.

In my Controller I have:

```
[HttpGet("GetGallery")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetGallery()
{
    List<GalleryImage> galleryImagesDB = await _context.GalleryImages
        //.Include(a => a.ImageTags)
        .ToListAsync();

    return Ok(galleryImagesDB);
}
```

My Blazor page has:

```
private List<GalleryImage> galleryImages = new();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        galleryImages = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<GalleryImage>>("api/Gallery/GetGallery");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error in Gallery.OnInitializedAsync : {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

This works fine to retrieve a List of GalleryImages from the database. However, when I uncomment the line

```
.Include(a => a.ImageTags)
```

then it fails. If I break at the return then galleryImages correctly contains a List of GalleryImages, and any that have been Tagged include a List of GalleryImageTags. But I get an error in the Chrome console:

> Error in Gallery.OnInitializedAsync : Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

What am I doing wrong?

Client and Server are both using .Net 5.0.

Comment: Pretty sure the problem here is that there is a circular reference where the image and tag reference each other. You should consider sending a object where the reference only goes one way.

Comment: `[JsonIgnore] ` on one of the collections to stop the circular serialisation

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it. @BrianParker if you add that as an answer then I'll credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference. This will return from the DB but will cause the serialisation error. You can put `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on one of the collections to prevent to circular serialisation.